# Mysql. Выбор листьев дерева

Tags: myisam, mysql

```
`table4`:

id(int), id_parent(int), name(varchar), level(int)
```

Выбор элементов без детей

```
SELECT *
    FROM `table4` AS `p`
LEFT JOIN `table4` AS `c` ON `c`.`id_parent` = `p`.`id`
WHERE `p`.`level` =5
    AND `c`.`id` IS NULL
ORDER BY `p`.`id`
```

Происходит непозволительно долго(85К записей, максимальный уровень сейчас - 26) - около 30 секунд. Уверен, опять накосячил с индексами (сейчас id - primary, auto increment);

Можно ли как-то оптимизировать операции с иерархией, не прибегая к nested set?
Очень уж у нее громоздкие и запутанные insrertы.

P.S. совсем листья, то есть элементы, которые не могут в принципе иметь детей - в отдельной таблице.

Comment: Пора давно перейти на **NESTED SETS** там удобнее делать выборки и быстрее.

Comment: не прибегая к nested set// я же написал. =( Выборки-то там сказка. А, вот вставка, редактирование, перемещение, копирование... - happy tree friends.

Comment: >А, вот вставка, редактирование, перемещение, копирование... - happy tree friends.

Ну не скажи, если сделать нормальные функции обхода CRUD, то все достаточно просто. Ну да обход большого кол-ва записей при удалении/вставки/копировании есть такое, но это разовые и не постоянные действия с деревьями.

Comment: Ладно. Ча будет еще вопрос... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А так?

```
select t1.id, t1.id_parent, t1.name
from table4 t1 left join table4 t2 on t1.id = t2.id_parent
where t1.level = 5
group by t1.id, t1.id_parent, t1.name
having count(t2.id)=0
```

Comment: Так даже медленнее. У меня все-таки подозрение, что надо как-то оптимизировать индексы. Либо и правда переходить к nested set.

Comment: возможные индексы:

* id_parent
* id_parent+level

Comment: ЙЕС. Оно: доп. индекс по id_parent+level. спасибо огромное.
Просто не знал, что индексы могут иметь неуникальное значение. Что только не узнаешь...

Answer (score 2):

Изредка хочется вспомнить SQL

Так не сработает ?

```
SELECT * FROM table4 AS p WHERE p.level = 5 AND p.id NOT IN (SELECT id_parent FROM table4)
```

Собственно идея в том, что лист это запись, на которую никто по id_parent не ссылается (или я ошибаюсь?). Вот и будем выбирать только тех с уровня 5, чей id нигде в id_parent не прописан.

Если так, то могу предположить, что MySQL может эффективно реализовать такой запрос без индексов.

Comment: без индексов... не будет. Хотя, вынужден признать, что скорость работы завидная: почти вчетверо быстрее предложенного мной варианта. 0.02с и 0.07с.

Другое дело, у вашего способа, по-идее, расходуется много больше памяти, если я хоть что-нибудь в чем-нибудь понимаю.

Comment: Не знаю, как это реализует MySQL, но по идее достаточно 2-х сортировок временных файлов (одна для всего множества id\_parent, другая для записей с level=5 по id) и слияния (точнее операции "обратной" слиянию).

Не знаю, как коротко и правильно это описать, но думаю идея ясна. 

85К записей и **последовательное** чтение - это д.б. быстро.

Comment: Еще по поводу памяти-скорости. "Руками на Си" с учетом конкретного размера таблицы я бы делал так:

Последовательное чтение всех записей table4. Для каждой записи 

1. Отбор во временный файл "возможный" результат, т.е. записи с level=5;

2. Выборка в массив в памяти всех id_parent (85K int займут 340KB, (влезет в кэш CPU!));

После прохода сортировка массива id_parent.

Проход по временному файлу. Двоичным поиском ищем id в массиве id_parent (скажем 16 проверок). Если не нашли, то отправляем эту запись в результат.

Удаляем временный файл.

До физической записи данных на диск дело не дойдет.