# Составление правильного запроса в MYSQL

Tags: база-данных, sql, запрос, select, mysql

Есть 2 таблицы.

```
ТабПользователи (ТабПольз.Айди, ТабПольз.БоссАйди)
ТабЗаявка (ТабЗаявка.Айди ТабЗаявка.ПользАйди)
```

Логика: В таблице с юзерами мы храним айди юзера и айди босса этого юзера. В заявках храним айди заявки и айди того, кто создал заявку

Цель: создать запрос, который покажет все заявки заданного юзера и всех его подчинённых, без лишней информации.

Я пробовал так вытащить подчененных:

```
SELECT * from табзаяв where Табзаяв.айди=ТабПольз.Боссайди
```

Затем добавляю себя с помощью `union`.

Comment: вы случаем не из 1С?

Comment: ^))) НЕТ!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select id from Requests where user_id in (
   select id from Users where id = %boss_id% or boss_id = %boss_id%
)
order by user_id
```

Вот как-то так можно попробовать

%boss_id% заменить на нужное число

Comment: я страшно признателен! Извиняюсь, за наглость, но могли бы вы расписать некоторые вещи, я новичёк и не до конца понимаю такие вещи как order by - это вроде сортировка, или это отсеевание повторяющихся? и во всех местах словой id для полного представления указать чей этот айди типа requests.id или users.id! И возможно ли мне в первом селекте место id поставить *, не нарушит ли это ничего? А по пошарив по офф. документации столько всяких оговорок на каждый оператор, что блин разбежаться страшно :)))

Comment: 1. здесь в запрос входит вложенный запрос. сначала формируется массив id пользователей, а потом выбираются все заявки пользователей с этими id.

2. id пользователей вытаскиваются по условию, что вводимый id равен либо id пользователя, либо его руководителю. если возможна двойственная интерпретация, то последует ошибка и необходимо уточнить из какой таблицы именно нужно...

3. id относится к той таблице, которая указана в этом запросе.

4. order by [asc / desc] - это сортировка. asc- по алфавиту, desc- против. если не указано, то применяется asc.

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо! На таких как вы - держится мир. Ни капли не преувеличено! Так, как из миллионов людей только один или два находятся, которые не выёживаются своим проффесианализмом, не давят понтами и не послывают в мануал всего мускула, а отвечают точным ответом, помогают сразу и по существу и объясняют понятно, так как это сделали вы! Огромное, спасибо! Думаю вас ждёт замечательное будущее, по крайней мере, я вам этого желаю!

Comment: @kindosKZ Уважаемый аксакал, не раскроете ли великий секрет, а сколько лет Вы потратили на опрос миллионов "проффесианалов"?

Answer (score 1):

Кажется, здесь вы найдете решение: [Mysql. Выбор листьев дерева](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/150343/myisam-mysql-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0)

Comment: Посмотрел. Не осилил, пока ищу ещё варианты. Но, всё равно, огромное спасибо. В Эрудицию закину...